# Getting values from a list using foreach

Tags: c#

I have list that have values like"

```
[0] = "{ id = ES10209005, views = 501 }"
[1] = "{ id = HYT0209005, views = 5678}"
[3] = "{ id = POI0209005, views = 4568}"
```

I would like to pass the values(id,views) to a method using a for each loop.

method(id,views)

Something like:

```
foreach (string v in updatereponse)
{

method()
}
```

How do I isolate each value(id,views) from each row in the list then pass it to the method?

Answer (score 2):

The list contains just a bunch of strings, anything based on this to fix the problem would be just a workaround (e.g. string parsing). You should really switch to a strongly typed model, e.g. define a class `ViewCount`:

```
public class ViewCount
{
   public string Id {get;set;}
   public int Views {get;set;}
}
```

You can then use a `List<ViewCount>` populate the list:

```
List<ViewCount> viewcounts = new List<ViewCount>();
viewCounts.Add(new ViewCount() { Id = "ES10209005", Views = 501 });
```

Since each ViewCount instance has  `Id` and `Views` properties you can now do the proper thing:

```
foreach (var item  in updatereponse)
{
    method(item.Id, item.Views);
}
```

If you are saving this data in a file, an alternative would be to use XML instead of custom strings, then you could use Linq to XML to populate a `List<ViewCount>`, e.g. using a simple XML like this:

```
<ViewCounts>
  <ViewCount id="ES10209005" views="501" />
</ViewCounts>
```

You can then load your list:

```
XElement viewXml = XElement.Load("test.xml");
List<ViewCount> viewCounts = viewXml.Descendants("ViewCount")
                                    .Select(x => new ViewCount()
                                    {
                                        Id = (string)x.Attribute("id"),
                                        Views = (int)x.Attribute("views")
                                    }).ToList();
```

Comment: item is a string and therefore it has no id or views property.

Comment: Sorry but the above "item." does not give me id and views in the list. Can I do this with a lambada expression. The list is populated at after executing my program

Comment: Updated answer - use a strongly typed model

Comment: Great answer. I am using an I inumerable object now

Answer (score 0):

You can use String methods to retrieve the items (use Split and SubString for example) or you can use a regular expression.

E.g.

```
var list = UpdateResponse[0].Split("=,} ") ;
```

will result in a list split by all these characters (including space).

Then check the correct indices to use (use a debugger for that). Then you get something like:

```
var id = list[5];
var views = list[8];
```

(note: check the indices 5 or 8, they are just a guess).

Comment: Why did everybody get a downvote? They all lead to an answer.

Comment: Paid it forward.. Maybe whoever it is just got dumbed or something :D

Comment: Thanks. And for the one who downvoted: only very wrong or confusing answers should be downvoted, in most other cases a remark is more appriate.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (string v in updateresponse)
{
  var values = v.Split(",");
  var id = values[0].Replace("{ id = ", "").Trim();
  var view = values[1].Replace("views = ", "").("}","").Trim();
  method(id, value);
}
```

Comment: Is there a cleaner way to achieve get the id and view using lambada expression

Comment: @user1204195 unfortunately when you have data stored in strings like this, the solution will be more or less a variation of these steps but not much cleaner

Comment: who is giving everybody a down vote without even an explanation!! lol :D

Comment: @Bassam Mehanni I upvoted all answers to compensate for it (except for my own which of course is not possible).

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way...you may want to add error checking:

```
String Data = "{ id = ES10209005, views = 501 }";

String[] Segments = Data.Split(new char[] { ' ', ',' });

string ID = Segments[3];

int views = int.Parse(Segments[7]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the structure of your String is like you showed us always, this can work for you.

```
// First split id and views part.
String[] firstSplit = v.Split(',');

// Get the respected value for each part.
String id    = firstSplit[0].Split('=')[1].Trim();
String views = firstSplit[1].Split('=')[1].Trim().Replace("}","");
```